# C++ how to manage iterators of contiguous dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, stl

I have been trying to figure out an efficient way of managing dynamic arrays which I may change occasionally but would like to randomly access and iterate over often.

I would like to be able to:

- store the array in a continuous data block (reduce cache misses)
- access each element individually and independently of the array handle (pointers > indices)
- resize the array (dynamic)

So in order to achieve this I have been trying things out using `std::vector<T>::iterator`, and it worked very well, until recently, when I resized the vector (e.g. calling `push_back()`) that I was storing iterators of. All the iterators became invalid, because they were pointing to stale memory.

Is there any efficient (possibly STL-)way of keeping the iterator pointers up to date? Or do I have to update each Iterator manually?

Is this whole approach even worthwhile? Should I stick with indices?

EDIT: 
I have used indices before and it was ok, but I have changed my approach because it still wasn´t good. I would always have to drag the entire array into scope and the indices could be easily used for any array. also there is no perfect way of defining a "NULL" index (none I know about).

What about the option to update all pointers along with a resize operation? All you would have to do is to store the original `vector::begin`, resize the `vector` and afterwards update all pointers to `vector.begin() + (ptr - prevBegin)` and resize operations is already something you should try to avoid.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a `std::array<std::vector<some_type>, some_size>`

Comment: Use a `std::vector` and use `size_t` indexes instead of iterators.

Comment: What do you mean by "pointers > indices" ?

Comment: @snow_abstraction an index is useless if you don't also have the starting point of the array, so you need two pieces of information. The pointer goes directly to the element itself (but can be invalidated), so you don't need anything else.

Comment: @ChrisDodd he says *independently of the array handle*, so he can't use an index into the array without a handle to the array

Comment: @SteveLorimer: then use a `std::pair<std::vector<..> *, size_t>` or even wrap it into a class that supports `operator*()`/`operator->()`

Comment: You can easily use an index of -1 to indicate NULL. It's not possible to update pointers, because there's no master list of all the pointers to the array that exist in your program.

Comment: @ChrisDodd that's worthy of an answer. Although I'd use a reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: a reference makes it non-assignable, which may be relevant.

Comment: @ChrisDodd if he ever removes an item, or adds one anywhere other than the back of the vector some of the indices will be invalidated too. Not sure if he needs that kinds of functionality

Comment: @stimulate I still honestly don't see the problem with just keeping a reference to the vector `v`, and the index `i`, and accessing elements as `v[i]`. This will always be valid. The closest thing you've given to an explanation is the "dragging the array in scope", and the null thing. The latter is very easy to address, and for the former I don't see the problem with hanging on to a reference to the vector. You can wrap it up as per Chris' suggestion but that's basically a wrapper over the same thing. It's not as nice as a single pointer, but not a big deal either.

Comment: @NirFriedman This will be the solution I am going for although it is still not a _perfect_ solution, as I have to keep a reference to the vector. But as you have already argued, it might be impossible to achieve all 3 goals.

Comment: @stimulate well, you can wrap vector in a class, register all pointers with that class by giving it a pointer to a pointer, and then call push_back and resize through that wrapping class, which will check for invalidation and update all pointers. Doable, just kind of messy and fragile and imho worse than reference plus index.

Comment: @NirFriedman what about storing an array of pointers to each array element along with the array, and passing references to these pointers out of the class? The class could update each pointer in the pointer-array with each resize, which it had to resize along with the actual array anyways. And using the references you could access the managed pointers and directly access the element.

Comment: "*also there is no perfect way of defining a "NULL" index (none I know about)*" - you could just use -1, if you use signed indexes.  Otherwise, use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) instead.

Comment: @stimulate Sure, you can do that too, it is basically equivalent to what Chris suggested but with centralized storage though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can use -1 regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fully achieving all 3 of your goals is impossible. If you are fully contiguous, then you have one memory block with a finite size, and the only way to get more memory is to ask for more memory, which will not be contiguous with the memory you already have. So you have to sacrifice at least one requirement, to at least some degree:

- If you are willing to partly sacrifice contiguity, you can use a `std::deque`. This is an array-of-arrays kind of structure. It doesn't invalidate references, for I think any operation that increases its size. It depends on the details of your data type but generally its performance is much closed to a contiguous array than a linked list. Well done but old (5 year) benchmarks: https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html. Another option is to write a chunking allocator, to use either with `deque` or another structure. This is quite a bit more work though.
- If you can use indices, then you can just use a `vector`
- If you don't need to resize, you can still just use a `vector` and never resize it.

Unless you have a good reason, I would stick with indices. If your main performance bottlenecks are iteration related over a large number of elements (as your contiguity requirement implies), then this whole indexing thing should really be a non-issue. If you do have a very good reason for avoiding indices (which you haven't stated), then I would profile the `deque` versus the `vector` on the main loop operation to see how much worse the `deque` really does. It might be barely worse, and if neither `deque` nor `vector` work well enough for you, the next alternatives are quite a bit more work (probably involving allocators or a custom data structure).

Comment: Reaching out and updating everything that points to you is difficult, you'd have to store pointers of some kind to all the vector's clients somewhere near the vector. It's more logical to have everyone who needs to access the ith element of your vector v, store both a reference to v and and i itself. I'm not really sure I see the problem with that? Also you can do a null index as -1; this will wrap around to the largest unsigned value 2^64-1 most likely, probably more memory than you have ;-).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs, if you can use the following data structure:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>
```

then no matter how the vector is resized, if you access your data via a `Foo*`, the pointer to foo will not be invalidated.

As the number of `Foos` you need to store in your vector changes, the vector may need to resize it's internal contiguous block of memory, which means any iterators you have pointing inside the vector **will be invalidated** when the vector resizes.

*(You can read more [here](http://kera.name/articles/2011/06/iterator-invalidation-rules-c0x/) on C++0x iterator invalidation rules)*

However, since the object stored in the vector is a pointer to an object elsewhere in the heap, the pointed-to-object (`Foo` in this example), will **not be invalidated**.

Note that the vector *owns* `Foo` (as alluded to by `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`), whilst you can store a *non-owning* pointer to `Foo` by keeping a `Foo*` as the means of accessing your `Foo` data.

So long as the vector outlives your need to access `Foo` via your `Foo*`, then you will not have any lifetime issues.

**So in terms of your requirements:**

- store the array in a continuous data block (reduce cache misses)

**yes**, `std::vector` achieves this

- access each element individually and independently of the array handle (pointers > indices)

**yes**, store a `Foo*` as your means of accessing each element individually, and that remains independent of the array handle (`vector::iterator`)

- resize the array (dynamic)

**yes**, `std::vector` achieves this, automatically, resizing for you when you need it to.

**Bonus:**

Using a smart pointer (in this example `std::unique_ptr`) in the vector means memory management is also handled automatically for you. (Just make sure you don't try to access a `Foo*` *after* the vector is destroyed.

**Edit:**

It has been pointed out in the comments that storing a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` in the vector violates your requirement for the objects to be stored in contiguous memory (if indeed that is what you mean by *store the array in contiguous memory*, as the vector's underlying array *will* be contiguous, but accessing the `Foo` objects will incur an indirection).

However, if you use a suitable allocator (eg arena allocator) for both the `vector` and the `Foo` objects, then you will have a higher chance of suffering fewer cache misses, as your `Foo` objects will exist near to the memory used by your `vector`, thereby having a higher chance of being in cache when iterating over the vector.

Comment: To be blunt, this should not be getting upvotes. The actual data here is not being stored contiguously and iterating over this vector will potentially cause piles of cache misses, contradicting a requirement of the question.

Comment: @NirFriedman fair enough - I've added a comment about using a suitable allocator to get the objects *near* to the vector's buffer

Comment: I agree with Friedman, how is the data of all `Foo`s stored continuously? The pointers to each `Foo` might be, but unless I store all `Foo`s in a `vector` they could be allocated anywhere. But when using `std::vector` to store all `Foo`s I will still invalidate all the `unique_ptr<Foo>`s pointers when resizing the `vector<Foo>`

Comment: @stimulate you can't achieve all 3 requirements at the same time - but by using an allocator you can get close

Comment: @SteveLorimer You can obviously use an allocator but really you are just shifting the problem around, once you have a good allocator written you can also just used it with a linked list, which a vector of unique_ptr's is very similar to, or another data structure like a `deque`. The vector of unique_ptr's suggestion itself (which your answer is focused on) doesn't buy you much, in fact buys you nothing over a linked list that I can think of.

Comment: Re:Edit: Storing the actual data (all `Foo`s) in a contiguous memory block has highest priority to me. I would prefer updating each pointer with each memory reallocation.

Comment: @stimulate Chris Dodd's suggestion of using `std::pair<std::vector<..> *, size_t>` or similar to store indices into the array seems like a good option for you then (so long as you only add at the back and don't ever remove any)